# Where is my Sublime Preferences file?

Tags: macos, file, command-line, terminal, sublimetext

I'm using the excellent [Sublime Text 3 editor](http://www.sublimetext.com/3) on my Mac for which I want to turn off word wrap. So I went to `Preferences > Settings - Default`, which opens up a settings file. Unfortunately I am unable to edit the file, so I wanted to lookup the file on the command line. I hovered over the file in Sublime, which shows me the location of the file:

[image]

I then tried to go to that folder, but to my surprise there is no `Default` folder in the `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/` folder:

```
 $ ls -la ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/
total 280
drwx------   7 kramer65  staff     238 17 okt 13:48 .
drwx------   8 kramer65  staff     272  8 okt 16:23 ..
-rw-r--r--@  1 kramer65  staff    6148  8 okt 16:25 .DS_Store
drwxr-xr-x@ 18 kramer65  staff     612 14 jul 01:49 Jedi - Python autocompletion
-rw-r--r--@  1 kramer65  staff  132375 17 okt 13:45 Package Control.sublime-package
drwxr-xr-x  24 kramer65  staff     816 17 okt 13:48 SublimeCodeIntel
drwx------   7 kramer65  staff     238 17 okt 13:48 User
```

and here I'm stuck. How can it be that I am looking at a file, which doesn't seem to exist?

Does anybody know what I'm doing wrong here? How can I find this file to disable the wordwrapping? All tips are welcome!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The file you were looking for is actually very close

> ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
>   3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings

that's indeed the file shown through the menu. I agree its location isn't as intuitive as it could be.

Answer (score 8):

The correct answer is: **it depends** on:

1. What OS you are using. (MacOS, Win, Cygwin, Linux)
2. How you installed it. (By default installer or as a stand-alone.)

Here's the default (installer) list:

```
MacOS:   ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Linux:   ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
Windows: C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings
```

For a **stand-alone** installation, it will be in:
**`<install path>/Data/Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`**.

The settings files are consulted in this order:

```
    Packages/Default/Preferences.sublime-settings
    Packages/Default/Preferences (<platform>).sublime-settings
    Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings
    <Project Settings>
    Packages/<syntax>/<syntax>.sublime-settings
    Packages/User/<syntax>.sublime-settings
    <Buffer Specific Settings>
```

So generally you should place your settings in:
**`.../Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`**.

---

PS. Yes, I know OP asked for MacOS, but everyone else will also end up on this page.

Comment: For anyone on the new [Sublime Text 4](https://www.sublimetext.com/blog/articles/sublime-text-4), it seems like something has changed here as the `Default` package no longer exists on the filesystem.  It seems they are doing some voodoo magic in ST4 to make the default preferences doc *appear* to still exist at this path, but I'm not yet able to locate the platform-specific preferences docs.

Comment: @TaylorEdmiston Thanks for update. Unfortunately I'm still a happy ST3 user, so I have not had a chance to look at ST4 yet. So if someone finds a solution let me know, and I'll add an update to this answer. Another thought is that since `Default` is not supposed to be touched, perhaps they have hardcoded it? It may help to search your drive for the files. Perhaps using `find` under *WSL* or *Cygwin*, which are good at finding files usually hidden by the OS.

Comment: I am using ST4 running on Linux and just opened the settings and the file is in:
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/Preferences.sublime-settings

Answer (score 4):

You must open *Settings - User* instead of *Settings - Default*. *Settings - Default* contains default settings and it should not be editable.

So just go to *Preferences/Settings - User* and add following content to disable word wrap:

```
{
    "word_wrap": false
}
```

Comment: Although I still don't get why the file doesn't exist, this is indeed a solution to my problem. Thanks! :)